# When should SignalSpy be used in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qttest

I'm seeing an issue in my QML animation, where very rarely, a state transition animation does not happen. I was searching online why that might be and came across `SignalSpy`. How and when should someone use it? The example is confusing, I thought it was certain that every time you click a button, the `clicked` signal would be emitted, why do we need to test this? I was just looking for an explanation that goes beyond the few lines mentioned in the documentation here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qttest-signalspy.html

Comment: That's part of QtTest, which is Qt's unit test framework. The example they use in the docs is pretty simplistic, but imagine you have a signal that could be emitted from multiple places, or multiple times from the same place. This allows you to verify that it gets called the number of times you expect.

Comment: The [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsignalspy.html) on the C++ side might give you more insight.

Comment: What could cause it to not emit the number of times we expect it to? I'm trying to understand why we would need a test case like this. @JarMan

Comment: Well, imagine there is some logic behind when you emit a signal, like maybe every time you get a network error, for instance. You just want a simple sanity check that says you got the signal (or didn't). It's not testing Qt's ability to deliver the signal. It's testing that you emitted what you expect to emit.

Comment: Inspired from this post I added the SignalSpy to my test cases. Guess what...I found out that a dataChanged signal from my data store was triggered two times. Fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Ah...and don't forget to call spy.clear() if you reuse it ;)